# how to write a query to return a tables data types

Tags: mysql

ive forgotten wha tthe query is to return a tables columns data types such as ,char , varchar, int, smallint and such if anyone could refresh my memory i'd appriciate itt im using Mysql Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

My memory refreshed itself you use the describe keyword thanks all.